# css active selector exception for a child element

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a `div` with `:active` selector effect,
this `div` contains a child little `div` which contains some buttons

Now -of course- when the parent `div` is clicked, the `:active` effect will be triggered, but also when one of the buttons inside the child-div is clicked the same thing happens, which is what I don't want, (it feels like the guest has clicked both the button and the parent `div`, very annoying)

What I want is: the `:active` effect is to be triggered only when the parent `div` is clicked, not when one of the elements inside a child-div is clicked.
Is it possible? I don't mind using JS or jQuery.

In the following example, the border goes red whether I click on the div or the button inside it:

```css
#parent-div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
#parent-div:active {
  border: 3px solid red;
}
#child-div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent-div">
  <div id="child-div">
    <button>Hello</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: sorry I updated the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be achieved with CSS only:

```css
#parent-div:active:not(:focus-within) {
  border: 3px solid red;
}
```

Sadly, [`:focus-within`](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors/#the-focus-within-pseudo) is not widely supported, but you can use a [JS polyfill](https://gist.github.com/aFarkas/a7e0d85450f323d5e164).

```css
#parent-div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
#parent-div:active:not(.focus-within) {
  border: 3px solid red;
}
#child-div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://gist.githubusercontent.com/aFarkas/a7e0d85450f323d5e164/raw/"></script>
<div id="parent-div">
  <div id="child-div">
    <button>Hello</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you it worked !
(for some reason the snippet you posted did not work on chrome (it did on firefox), but it worked on my website)

Comment: @MotassemMK True, Chrome says `Refused to execute script from 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/aFarkas/a7e0d85450f323d5e164/raw/' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled`. I don't know how to request github to serve the proper MIME type, but copying the code to your server should work.

Comment: yep that's what I did and it worked, thank you.

Comment: `:focus-within` now works in `-webkit`http://webkit.org/b/140144